# Counting Numbers and words in a Text file Program

Tags: java, input

I need to do a simple program that counts the number of words and gives the total of the numbers in a text file. The program has to compute the sum and average of all the numbers.  The average is the sum divided by the count.The file counts the numbers and words together. It just prints 34.

```
//CAT DOG BIRD FISH
//1 2 3 4 5
//TURTLE LIZARD SNAKE
//6 7 8 9 10
//FISH SHARK
//11 12 13 14 15
//SPIDER FLY GRASSHOPPER ANT SCORPION
//16 17 18 19 20


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HomeWork8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String words, numbers, message;
        int numberWords = 0, countNumber = 0;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/Users/ME/Documents/Words and Numbers.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(fis);

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            words = in.next();

            numberWords++;

        }

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            in.useDelimiter("");
            numbers = in.next();
            countNumber++;
        }

        in.close();

        message = "The number of words read from the file was " + numberWords
                + "\nThe count of numbers read from the file was" + countNumber;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even use regular expressions to filter the words and numbers as is shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
String words, message;
int numberWords = 0, countNumber = 0;
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("src/WordsandNumbers.txt");
Scanner in = new Scanner(fis);

String numRegex   = ".*[0-9].*";
String alphaRegex = ".*[A-Za-z].*";

while (in.hasNext()) {
    words=in.next();
    if (words.matches(alphaRegex)) {
        numberWords++;
    }
    else if(words.matches(numRegex))
    {
        countNumber++;
    }        
}

in.close();

message = "The number of words read from the file was " + numberWords
        + "\nThe count of numbers read from the file was" + countNumber;

System.console().writer().println(message);
```

}

You need to have a single iteration through the content of the filerather than having 2 while loops.

Comment: I ran it but now it has "0" for words and for the numbers.

Comment: The regular expression is very basic and might not be enough to parse the required words and numbers. Could you share the text that you are trying to parse?

Comment: its 14 word and the count of number is 20: CAT DOG BIRD FISH
1 2 3 4 5
TURTLE LIZARD SNAKE
6 7 8 9 10
FISH SHARK
11 12 13 14 15
SPIDER FLY GRASSHOPPER ANT SCORPION
16 17 18 19 20

Comment: Hmm.. I am not sure, what might be going wrong at your end but the code works well and gives me the same result. Just to be sure I have updated my code to include the complete main function.

Comment: it i wanted to compute the sum and average of all the numbers by add each and dividing it by the total. 210/20 =10.5

Answer (score 3):

```
String pattern ="\\d";
        String word="shdhdshk 46788 jikdjsk 9 dsd s90 dsds76";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(word);
        int count=0;
        while (m.find()) {            
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
```

If you need to get the single number character count you can use **\d** . But If you are interested in whole number occurrence then you have to use **\d+** instead of **\d**. Ex: `46788,9,90,76`

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am beginner i haven't covered Matcher m = Pattern.compile just yet.

Answer (score 1):

Just before the second `while (in.hasNext()) {` you should reset the stream by adding the following code:

`in = new Scanner(fis);`

You should also revise your code for checking for numbers (I don't think you're checking for numbers anywhere).

Comment: Thank you for answering. i reset the stream but it didn't change. Can i check for the number by using char?